# CSS - How do I center a loading icon on a page that contains an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How do I center a loading icon on a page that contains an iframe ?

The iframe height is variable and it contains a table with some editing buttons such as Edit Delete. When one of the buttons is pressed, while the ajax call is working, I want to center the loading icon on the center of the screen, but instead it is centered on the center of the iframe, that depending on the data available ,the height could be anywhere between 1024px to 6000px. I'm using blockUI - jQuery for the loading icon. My CSS is the following :

```
var topOffset = $(window).height() / 2;
var leftOffset = $(window).width() / 2;
var style = {
  position: 'fixed',
  top: topOffset,
  left: leftOffset
};
```

I'm setting it to the the blockUI via jQuery.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like you'd be better off not using blockui (it might be hard to override it, and i guess you could set the same thing in less than 5 minutes, which would let you do whatever you want). Apart from this consideration, it might be hard for others to understand if your loader is inside your iframe, or above the iframe on the same page

Comment: Main page and iframe content from the same domain? Then it might be easier, if you put the loading indicator in the main page, and only trigger it from inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Found the answer:

var topOffset = **screen.height / 2;**

var leftOffset = **screen.width / 2;**